# Emacs indentation of objective-c block syntax

Tags: objective-c, emacs, cc-mode

I'm using `objc-mode` and in general the indentation works quite well, but I am having difficulty with the following code.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self someMethod];
});
```

Emacs tries to indent it like so:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self someMethod];
    });
```

Basically whenever there's a block inside a function / method call, it indents too much. The syntactic analysis for the 1st line of the block is (`arglist-cont-nonempty`, `statement-block-intro`). `statement-block-intro` is set to `'+`. `arglist-cont-nonempty` is set to `'(c-lineup-gcc-asm-reg c-lineup-arglist)`. In other words, just the defaults.

What should I do to get it to indent properly?

Comment: I Don't do objective-c so I don't know if this will mess up other aspects of indentation but setting statement-block-intro to 0 and block-close to '- worked for me